# Deprecated index warning when using QueryBuilder API but not with QueryBuilder servlet

Tags: search, aem

I have a simple AEM query

```
path=/content/bla/blabla/blablabla
type=cq:Page
p.limit=-1
orderby=path
```

This query executes fine using the `/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html` servlet, however when the same query is built and executed using QueryBuilder API (`ResourceResolver` adaptation to `Session` omitted for clarity, `QueryBuilder` injected using dependency injection `@Reference` as 'queryBuilder')

```
final Map<String,String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
            
            queryMap.put("path","/content/bla/blabla/blablabla");
            queryMap.put("type",NameConstants.NT_PAGE);
            queryMap.put("p.limit","-1");
            queryMap.put("orderby","path");

            Query query = queryBuilder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(queryMap),resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
            SearchResult result = query.getResult();
```

I can see the following in the AEM logs (which is not visible when running the query via the OOTB servlet).

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.index.lucene.LucenePropertyIndex This index is deprecated: /oak:index/lucene; it is used for query Filter(query=select [jcr:path], [jcr:score], * from [nt:base] as a where contains(*, '"/content/bla/blabla/blablabla"') /* xpath: //*[jcr:contains(., '"/content/bla/blabla/blablabla"')] */ fullText="/content/bla/blabla/blablabla", path=*). Please change the query or the index definitions.
```

What I'm trying to understand is what is different between the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

By debugging the code and continuously checking the logs I noticed this query does not cause any problems, it's caused by a different code snippet related to AEM [ReferenceSearch](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/commons/ReferenceSearch.html)